# web server keep yelling pdftk not found

Tags: apache2, php5

The original error message is

> sh: 1: pdftk: not found

That obviously leads to [this](https://github.com/mikehaertl/php-pdftk/issues/34). This is not the first time i encounter this issue, and I am sure that it's not the pdftk or php-pdftk.

Here is the background story, i develop web apps use php 5.4 on linuxmint.
Then the project discontinued. I already have a repository for that project, so i remove all the file. Several months later i decide to write all-new project on php 7, 7.3 at that time to be precise.

Suddenly i had to make new patch. Then, this is [the way i get pdftk](https://linuxhint.com/install_pdftk_ubuntu/). On terminal, i can play with the pdftk cli, like print the current version. But still, the webserver says same error.

**Clarifications found in comments**:

i think it related to permission, the binary already installed. i can use it via terminal.

Comment: pdftk is a package that you have to install.

However:
pdftk is obsolete and disappears from more and more distributions.


And sometimes it's virtually impossible to compile it from sources due to some obsolete dependencies.

If you can modify your code, then replace calls to pdftk with calls to something different, for example stapler  https://pypi.org/project/stapler/
stapler can be installed with pip install stapler (I'd recommend to use a python virtualenv or to install with `pip install --user`)

Comment: However. Stapler might also be soon end of life as it is written in python2 and python2 will be end of life beginning 2020

Comment: thank you, but i think it reated to permission, the binary already installed. i can use it via terminal.

Answer (score 1):

If `pdftk` is usable from a user logon (on the terminal as you say), then there are a few options:

Permissions: check that the file has the [right permissions](https://www.linux.com/tutorials/understanding-linux-file-permissions/), enabling everyone to execute it.

Environment: When you type `pdftk` on the command line, the interpreter (Shell, Bash, etc) knows to look in various places for the binaries. For example, it will look in `/usr/bin`. Where it looks is set in the `PATH` environment variable (see `echo $PATH`). However, that's in your user configuration. PHP running under Apache web server might not have this environment. So in your code it is best to make the call to the full path. What's the path? You can find out by running `which pdftk` in your terminal. Giving the full path in PHP code will circumvent the `PATH` problem.

Other possibly relevant posts in regards to permissions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17151946/executing-a-shell-script-from-a-php-script
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11649884/shell-exec-allow-specific-program-to-run-under-apache-user
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28639918/allow-php-apache-to-shell-execute-commands-on-ubuntu
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44529612/web-local-application-apache-run-a-shell-script

Comment: i try few times on setting the perm, but i am giving up. Thanks tho

Answer (score 0):

The way i get pdftk is via snap, sadly it has few limitations.
Even on mentioned articles is recommending to install via snap, but sadly it's also giving this issue.

Now the pdftk is available on mint, then you can uninstall pdftk via snap then install pdftk directly via apt.

```
apt install pdftk
```